# How to compile and boot Android kernel

Tags: android, c, kernel, android-source

I am interested in Android kernel level programming. Actually I am a Linux kernel programmer. I would like to know how to start with the kernel and how compile, boot and about the Kernel level subsystems (EX: How file systems are implemented etc..)  in Android. Any books or articles or a good guide to start are very much appreciated.

Comment: I thought Android *is* Linux?

Comment: @Carl Even though its linux its highly customized OS. I would like to know about android internals, about boot code, How it maintains platform independence etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Android kernel is a Linux kernel with only a few modifications (the rest of Android has nothing to do with Linux).

There's a [nice list of modifications on the Embedded Linux Wiki](http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features). This page also has several links that should interest you.

The most important feature for everyday Android development is [binders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html), an Android-specific interprocess communication mechanism, though they're usually used via higher-level interfaces.

The source of the Android kernel is at https://android.googlesource.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather short answer but it should be pretty helpful.

[Android Sources](http://source.android.com/) is definitely the right entry point for you.

There you will find the sources, how to setup your development environment for developing Android and how to build it.